# Pigpio Hardware PWM callback is slow

Tags: python, hardware, pwm, pigpio

I am trying to drive a servo motor with Raspberry pi. I have selected pigpio library to access GPIO. I need to send a specific number of pulses with a given frequency. But when I callback a function to count the pulses, it is taking more time than I expected. Is this normal, or my coding is wrong or inefficient? Pl. clarify. thanks in advance.

'''python3

```
import time
import pigpio
pi=pigpio.pi()

def pulseCounter():
global Count,i

if (i<7):
    i=i+1;
else:
    i=0
    Count= Count+1
    #print("Count= % 2d"%(Count ))




pi.set_mode(18,pigpio.ALT5)
Freq = 1600
Count = 0
i=0

pi.hardware_PWM(18, Freq, 500000)

t=time.time()
while (Count < 200):
    pi.callback(18,0,pulseCounter())
elapsedTime=time.time() - t
print("Elapsed time = ",elapsedTime)    

pi.write(18, 0) 
'''
```

Thanks, My aim is to develop a 3 axis servo controlled CNC milling test rig for laboratory use. The driver is Gecko 320X. Encoder resolution is 4000ppr. The requirement is to generate 3 pulse trains on three IOpins. (Max. frequency may be around 15k ) Need to count the number of pulses while sending. Planing to use three threads for three axes for simultaneous working. Using Raspberry pi 3 b. Please suggest the best way to proceed with this setup.

Comment: You are creating 200 callbacks. So pulse counter will be called 200 times for each pulse. That will be slow. You would normally set up a callback once. Why 1600  Hz? Any how use waves and a wave chain to send a known number of short pulses.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The frequency is selected depending on the required RPM of the motor. I haven't use waves. But I tried software pulses and it is not consistent. PWM does not allow to select the required frequency. I'm not familier with wave chain. I will try it.

Comment: If you explain (in your question) what you are trying to achieve you are more likely to get useful help.  Servos are not driven in the way you seem to be doing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your library. It is very easy and useful.  I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: Any suggestions please???